# Error UnicodeDecodeError: 'iso2022_jp' codec can't decode bytes in position 7572-7573: illegal multibyte sequence

Tags: python-3.x, unicode, html-email

I am iterating through emails and converting to plain text and adding to a data frame in order to run some machine learning. This all works fine for the majority of emails but I keep getting this error and I'm kinda stuck.

Not sure where to go with this one. Any research I find is in Japanese.

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from html2text import HTML2Text

```
import pandas as pd

import easyimap
import getpass
import email

from datetime import datetime
from email.utils import parsedate_to_datetime




def to_text(html, rehtml=False):
    parser = HTML2Text()
    parser.wrap_links = False
    parser.skip_internal_links = True
    parser.inline_links = True
    parser.ignore_anchors = True
    parser.ignore_images = True
    parser.ignore_emphasis = True
    parser.ignore_links = True
    text = parser.handle(html)
    text = text.strip(' \t\n\r')
    if rehtml:
        text = text.replace('\n', '<br/>')
        text = text.replace('\\', '')
    return text 

imap_password = getpass.getpass()


user = 'email@email.com'
host = 'outlook.office365.com'
password = imap_password


folders =  ('"INBOX/Americas/Not Raised"', '"INBOX/Americas/Raised"', '"INBOX/APAC/Not Raised"', '"INBOX/APAC/Raised"', '"INBOX/Consolidated"', 
            '"INBOX/Consolidated/Not Raised"', '"INBOX/Consolidated/Raised"', '"INBOX/EMEA"', '"INBOX/EMEA/Not Raised"', '"INBOX/EMEA/Raised"')


df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Subject','Sender','From','To','Body','References','content_type', 'local_date_time', 
                          'Classification', 'in_reply_to','return_path', 'mime_version', 'message_id'])


for mailbox in folders:

    #Connect to mailbox read_only = True to ensure the mail is not marked as read.
    imapper = easyimap.connect(host, user, password, mailbox,read_only=True)

    #fetch each mail up to limit and return email data and add to a dataframe

    for mail_id in imapper.listids(limit=10000):
        mail = imapper.mail(mail_id, include_raw=True)
        #convert body to text using to_text function and add to dataframe
        df.loc[mail_id, ['Body']] = to_text(mail.body, rehtml=False)
        #return mail features to dataframe
        df.loc[mail_id, ['Subject']] = mail.title
        df.loc[mail_id, ['Sender']] = mail.sender
        df.loc [mail_id, ['From']] = mail.from_addr
        df.loc [mail_id, ['To']] = mail.to
        df.loc [mail_id, ['References']] = mail.references
        df.loc [mail_id, ['content_type']] = mail.content_type
        #converting the date to datetime and taking account of time difference changes
        date_= mail.date
        df.loc [mail_id, ['local_date_time']] = datetime.fromtimestamp(parsedate_to_datetime(date_).timestamp()).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        #parsing the keyword data from the raw mail data to provide the classification
        raw_data = mail.raw
        email_message = email.message_from_bytes(raw_data)
        df.loc [mail_id, ['Classification']] = email_message['Keywords']
        df.loc [mail_id, ['in_reply_to']] = mail.in_reply_to
        df.loc [mail_id, ['return_path']] = mail.return_path
        df.loc [mail_id, ['mime_version']] = mail.mime_version
        df.loc [mail_id, ['message_id']] = mail.message_id
```

All emails should be added to a data frame. Traceback error showing as:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-e9627be1e6e3> in <module>
     54 
     55     for mail_id in imapper.listids(limit=10000):
---> 56         mail = imapper.mail(mail_id, include_raw=True)
     57         #convert body to text using to_text function and add to dataframe
     58         df.loc[mail_id, ['Body']] = to_text(mail.body, rehtml=False)

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/easyimap/easyimap.py in mail(self, uid, include_raw)
    198         typ, content = self._mailer.uid('fetch', uid, self._fetch_message_parts)
    199         if typ == 'OK':
--> 200             mail = _parse_email(content, include_raw=include_raw)
    201             return mail
    202         else:

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/easyimap/easyimap.py in _parse_email(data, include_raw)
    246     if not isinstance(string_or_bytes_message, str):
    247         encoding = chardet.detect(string_or_bytes_message)
--> 248         string_or_bytes_message = string_or_bytes_message.decode(encoding.get('encoding'))
    249     if not isinstance(string_or_bytes_uid, str):
    250         encoding = chardet.detect(string_or_bytes_uid)

UnicodeDecodeError: 'iso2022_jp' codec can't decode bytes in position 7572-7573: illegal multibyte sequence
```

Comment: The `easyimap` library uses the `chardet` library to guess the encoding of one of your emails. But guessing encodings is not a guaranteed task. So `chardet` guesses the message had been encoded with "iso2022_jp", but since this is wrong, the subsequent decoding step fails. There's not much you can do, I'm afraid.

Comment: @Tajinder I rolled back your edit; it was not an improvement.

Comment: @tripleee Ok, was just trying to help. In case it seems that there is no improvement with my edit, its ok. :)

Comment: Actually, it's not OK to fill up the edit queues with spurious edits. I guess you are pushing to reach 2k rep, but you should not let your own targets override your judgment on what actually constitutes a contribution which should be rewarded with reputation points. Sadly, too many bogus edits go through because the review queues, too, attract too many users who are more interested in personal rep or badges than in actually contributing solid quality assurance.

Comment: Thanks! I've just added a step to export any problem emails to file and i can examine later.

Answer (score 2):

The `easyimap` library uses the `chardet` library to guess the encoding of one of your emails. But guessing encodings is not a guaranteed task. So `chardet` guesses the message had been encoded with "iso2022_jp", but since this is wrong, the subsequent decoding step fails.

I'm not sure there's much you can do.
If you can identify the problematic message, you can try to find out what its true encoding is.
If you succeed, there might be a way to override the guessing step and tell `easyimap` – maybe there's an optional `encoding=` parameter in the `imapper.mail()` method, you'd have to check the docs.

Comment: Thanks! I've just added a step to export any problem emails to file and i can examine later.

Answer (score 0):

ISO-2022-JP is a weird encoding with several variants that are formalized to various degrees. Characters like ① are valid in some variants but not in the base encoding. If you can manually specify the encoding to use for the mail, try one of these:

```
ISO-2022-JP-1
ISO-2022-JP-2
ISO-2022-JP-3
ISO-2022-JP-2004
CP932
```

CP932 is a Windows encoding and Outlook will pretend that ISO-2022-JP is the same thing even when it isn't. The 1/2/3 variants are sometimes used by Macs, particularly when sending characters not in the base encoding.

It would help if you could paste the original mail somewhere, though I understand that may be impossible for privacy reasons.

Comment: Thanks. I don't think it's possible to specify the encoding with easyimap. I've just added a step to export any problem emails to file and i can examine later.

Comment: I've just added some code to output the data to a file but I am noticing that the body is being cut off in the dataframe. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Spitting the problem emails to a file works.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from html2text import HTML2Text

import pandas as pd

import easyimap
import getpass
import email
import base64
import os
import email
import mimetypes

from datetime import datetime
from email.utils import parsedate_to_datetime




def to_text(html, rehtml=False):
    parser = HTML2Text()
    parser.wrap_links = False
    parser.skip_internal_links = True
    parser.inline_links = True
    parser.ignore_anchors = True
    parser.ignore_images = True
    parser.ignore_emphasis = True
    parser.ignore_links = True
    text = parser.handle(html)
    text = text.strip(' \t\n\r')
    if rehtml:
        text = text.replace('\n', '<br/>')
        text = text.replace('\\', '')
    return text 

imap_password = getpass.getpass()


user = 'email@email.com'
host = 'outlook.office365.com'
password = imap_password

#'
folders =  ('"INBOX/Americas/Not Raised"', '"INBOX/Americas/Raised"', '"INBOX/APAC/Not Raised"', '"INBOX/APAC/Raised"',
            '"INBOX/Consolidated/Not Raised"', '"INBOX/Consolidated/Raised"', '"INBOX/EMEA"', '"INBOX/EMEA/Not Raised"', '"INBOX/EMEA/Raised"')


df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Subject','Sender','From','To','Body','References','content_type', 'local_date_time', 
                          'Classification', 'in_reply_to','return_path', 'mime_version', 'message_id', 'folder_name'])


for mailbox in folders:

    #Connect to mailbox read_only = True to ensure the mail is not marked as read.
    imapper = easyimap.connect(host, user, password, mailbox,read_only=True)

    #fetch each mail up to limit and return email data and add to a dataframe

    for mail_id in imapper.listids(limit=5000):
        try:
            mail = imapper.mail(mail_id, include_raw=True)
            #convert body to text using to_text function and add to dataframe
            df.loc[mail_id, ['Body']] = to_text(mail.body, rehtml=False)
            #return mail features to dataframe
            df.loc[mail_id, ['Subject']] = mail.title
            df.loc[mail_id, ['Sender']] = mail.sender
            df.loc [mail_id, ['From']] = mail.from_addr
            df.loc [mail_id, ['To']] = mail.to
            df.loc [mail_id, ['References']] = mail.references
            df.loc [mail_id, ['content_type']] = mail.content_type
            #converting the date to datetime and taking account of time difference changes
            date_= mail.date
            df.loc [mail_id, ['local_date_time']] = datetime.fromtimestamp(parsedate_to_datetime(date_).timestamp()).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
            #parsing the keyword data from the raw mail data to provide the classification
            raw_data = mail.raw
            email_message = email.message_from_bytes(raw_data)
            df.loc [mail_id, ['Classification']] = email_message['Keywords']
            df.loc [mail_id, ['in_reply_to']] = mail.in_reply_to
            df.loc [mail_id, ['return_path']] = mail.return_path
            df.loc [mail_id, ['mime_version']] = mail.mime_version
            df.loc [mail_id, ['message_id']] = mail.message_id
            df.loc [mail_id, ['folder_name']] = mailbox
        except:

            #if error print email to file
            counter = 1
            for part in email_message.walk():
                if part.get_content_maintype() == "multipart":
                    continue 
                filename = part.get_filename()
                content_type = part.get_content_type()
                if not filename:
                    ext = mimetypes.guess_extension(content_type)
                    if not ext:
                        ext = '.bin'
                    if 'text' in content_type:
                        ext = '.txt'
                    elif 'html' in content_type:
                        ext = '.html'
                    filename = 'msg-part-%08d%s' %(counter, ext)
                counter += 1
            #save file
            date_ = datetime.fromtimestamp(parsedate_to_datetime(date_).timestamp()).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
            save_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "emails", date_, mail.title)
            if not os.path.exists(save_path):
                os.makedirs(save_path)
            with open(os.path.join(save_path, filename), 'wb') as fp:
                fp.write(part.get_payload(decode=True))
            counter += 1
```

Answer (score -1):

Guessing encodings is always difficult and prone to error. Even if you guess the "right" encoding, it's possible that the data contains illegal characters for that encoding.

The first thing to check is: Does the email `Content-type` header have a `Charset` attribute? If it does, this is probably the correct charset and you should use that, rather than falling back to chardet.

Comment: But the call to `chardet` isn't something the OP did, it happens inside the `easyimap` library. That library does attempt to get a charset from the metadata before falling back to chardet (though I'm not sure it's using the best strategy).

Comment: I'm sure the reason the library doesn't solely inspect this header is because it's not reliable.